# Running electrical cable across shallow stud resting on exterior wall

Tags: electrical, receptacle, studs

I'm attempting to add a new receptacle to power a wall-mounted projector. The nearby existing receptacle from which I'm powering the new one is on an adjacent stud bay. I was planning to fish the cable through a hole in the stud at least 1'' from the wall surface. However, the stud appears to be very shallow and does not appear to have enough depth to achieve this.

What are my options? Should I route the cable through the brick wall? Put a blank face plate to cover the cable run over the stud instead of patching with drywall? Remove the metallic conduit and drill a small hole for the bare NM cable?

[image: Cable run over stud]

[image: larger picture]

Comment: That's not a stud, it's just a furring strip that makes it easier to mount drywall to the concrete wall.  Normally MC cable needs to be set back in a stud.  I don't know what the rules are in a situation like this.  The furring strip is irrelevant.  You can cut and remove it where the cable crosses it, but if the cable is not allowed so close to the surface, the *entire* cable would be problematic.  You might need to run conduit on the surface.  I'm not answering because I don't know.

Comment: You will need nail guards to protect any wire that could be hit by a 1-1/2" (35mm) nail driven into the wall, in certain locations. NEC 300.3.  This is normally nail plates. That type of armored cable isn't armored enough to provide that protection. EMT conduit is.

Comment: What options do I have since the entire cable run is within 1-1/2'' from the surface? Run it through the concrete blocks?

Comment: Think the best would be surface conduit.  Imagine going though those blocks would be a big pain in the neck and below.  Think surface conduit would look somewhat decent.  Doubt EMT would fit behind the drywall anyway.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. I do feel that if I'm allowed to cut a section of the furring strip, I do have enough space for a 1/2'' conduit, which could be strapped to the block. I'd like to avoid surface conduit if possible.

Comment: Those furring strips are used more as a spacer than any structural use, so you can notch/cut them all the way to the cement block.

Comment: Once again, where in the world are you and what does _your_ local code require?

Comment: I'm located in the US/Florida.

Comment: On closer inspection of your first photo, it appears the MC is thicker than the furring and the drywall has been notched to accommodate the cable.  Yuck.  If you do that with EMT I think it will protrude out of the wall slightly, looking ghastly.   I think your choices here that are compliant and nice looking (as you seem to wish) are either EMT chased into the concrete or pretty conduit (eg wiremold) on the surface. You ask about "routing the cable" through the brick ... how exactly would you do that?

Comment: @harper what would you attach a nail plate if run inside the wall and how would a screw get purchase in Sheetrock to punch thru the flex? As long as 1-1/4 away from the furring strip it has passed inspection on many remodels for me but as I mentioned in my answer it looks like the flex is thicker than the space, I would use NMB in my jurisdiction but that is not a option for everyone.

Comment: @Ed probably by someone hitting it with a hammer because it's a nail.  But most people only drive nails near furring strips, so that is where the protection is needed. Reading my comment I may have cited the wrong article.  Ah, it's 300.4.  My fingers just type 300.3 automatically lol.

Comment: That’s why it has to be 1-1/4 away from the furring strip same in ceilings with nothing to attach a nail plate again how would you protect it? And this is why it would pass code dosent specify the depth of a void only the space to the side or from the face of the stud / furring strip in this case.@crip695 the minute you notch its cut the furring strip a nail plate is required as that is the support zone for the drywall and designed to be nailed to so a nail plate is required.

Comment: @jay613 I do have about 3/4'' of depth between the cinderblock and the drywall, which does appear to allow for a 1/2'' EMT. The drywall wasn't notched to accommodate the FMC in the picture but was lightly damaged while pulling the FMC over the furring strip.

Comment: Thinking of this in more detail: although technically there is enough space for a 1/2'' EMT, it would be almost impossible to "fish it" behind the wall and I would most likely need to cut open two long strips of drywall. Ed's solution to run the cable up and down would also seems difficult because I have almost no attic space above this area. Perhaps it could be done from below but I'm not sure how I would fish the NM cable horizontally above the joist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me that furring strip looks too thin to be able to notch for the flex and add a nail plate (by code the flex can not be deformed). What I have done is run up to the ceiling through the joist and down the bay where you want the new outlet. Make sure to run 1-1/4” away from the furring strip and when boring the hole in the joist make sure the hole is 1-1/4” back from the face.

Yes, this is more work to run up and then back down but you will also find the box fill on the shallow box does not have sufficient capacity for a junction or splice. I normally place the J-box in the ceiling standard cover and a decorative cover over that is designed to be removed.

I have used this method on quite a few remodels both with flex and with NMB or Romex and have always passed inspections.

Comment: So it's ok for vertical cable to be tightly sandwiched between drywall and concrete as long as it's 1-1/4 away from the furring horizontally?

Comment: Yes this is code compliant the code book provides examples with photos but off the top of my head I can’t remember the references one Is in the section on NM and one in the section on MC.